# Get Type in Robot Framework

Tags: python, automated-tests, robotframework

Could you tell me about how to get the variable type in Robot Framework.

```
${ABC}  Set Variable    Test
${XYZ}  Set Variable    1233
```

Remark: Get the variable Type such as string, int

get ${ABC} type = string

get ${XYZ} type = int

Answer (score 11):

This is what I use:

```
${type} =    Evaluate    type($temp).__name__
```

Note: it's good to have global string/int/float/list/dict/... examples for comparison than hard-coding the type values as they might differ depending on build.

Answer (score 8):

You can do e.g. this:
`${type_ABC}    Evaluate    type($ABC)`

Comment: Did you consider to accept/upvote the answer if it was useful for you? Of course you can try to wait for better one :)

Comment: Did you actually try your own example? I think the answer might surprise you for `${XYZ}`

Comment: Yes, I tried. It gives also 'str' as for ${ABC}. If you assign to ${XYZ} e.g. `Evaluate    1233`, you'll get 'int'. Am I wrong? I'll be more than happy if you could provide deeper explanation.

Comment: If you want to ensure that a variable is set as a Integer there is a different way of assigning it: `${XYZ}  Set Variable    ${1233}` note the `${1233}` will then result into a different log entry: `INFO : ${type_XYZ} = <type 'int'>`

Comment: Thanks @A.Kootstra