# How to check data type in robot framework?

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

[I read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42617970/get-type-in-robot-framework)

But when i'm passing string value in the variable at that time i'm getting error

Code : 
        `type(${value}).__name__`

Error:
`Evaluating expression 'type(Robot).__name__' failed: NameError: name 'Robot' is not defined`

String value converting as a variable

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove brackets `{}` around `value` and leave only `$value`.

---

Update to comment:
Robotframework treats everything as string unless you explicitly convert it to other datatype.

```
${value_str}    Set Variable    4
${value_number}    Convert To Number    ${value_str}
${type1}    Evaluate    type($value_str).__name__
${type2}    Evaluate    type($value_number).__name__
Log    ${type1}
Log    ${type2}
```

Comment: Yes, but when i remove brackets then it is always return me _str_ datatype whether it string or integer.

Comment: When you are using brackets than you are using value of variable, when you are using without brackets than you refer to actual variable.

Comment: Okay. Now its working, it was not working because i was getting value from the _Dialogs_ library of the robot framework. Thank you